# P/Invoke in ASP.NET (Dll not found exception)

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, dll

I have a .dll that I generated thorugh a C++ project. I have to use this dll in my ASP.NET project and I have written DllImport functions for the same in my project.

The static class inside `App_Code` has some `DllImport` functions

```
public static class Functions
{
    [DllImport("MyFav.dll", EntryPoint = "fnmain", 
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern StringBuilder fnmain();
}
```

Since I could not add the C++ dll directly as a reference in my ASP.NET project (because it is not a .NET assembly), I just copied into the top level directory. ( Name of ASP.NET Project-> Right Click -> Add Existing Item )

Now, when I try to run the project, I get the following error:

Exception:

> Unable to load DLL 'MyFav.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Any suggestions? Where has the .dll to be kept?

Comment: Maybe the dll is not found, maybe the dll found but you have use some libraries (like mfc) and not found on the directories that used by the asp.net account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.dll` should be in the `\bin` folder of your asp.net application.

Apparently there are rules for how dlls are resolved. See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx)

You could also try:

```
[DllImport("C:\path_to_dll\MyFav.dll", EntryPoint = "fnmain", 
 CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern StringBuilder fnmain();
```

If all this doesn't work, maybe your `MyFav.dll` has additional unresolved dependencies. You could use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check for these.

Comment: Also you can use LoadLibrary to load the DLL using a full path to it's current location.

Comment: I tried putting the .dll in \bin folder but didn't work, and used the full path then and it worked. But, for the full path of the .dll, although it finds the dll but I get an error when I try to fire the function. Error screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Qq5vM.png

Comment: @Cipher Well from what I can tell this probably is an error in `MyFav.dll` and not because you've referenced it wrong.

Comment: The .dll works fine in the C# desktop project but not in the ASP.NET project. Don't know for sure

Comment: **Maybe** you dll import should be `public static extern string fnmain();` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, but using Mono's XSP server.  For this server, the solution is to put the dll in the root of your web app (the parent folder of `./bin`).  That happens to also be the current working directory (when run from Xamarin Studio), which is presumaby related.

Answer (score 0):

if to be used with out path copy paste the `dll` to bin directory in your project folder
.